# Problems with copying Buffer in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, buffer

I'm trying to create method to append buffers.

Here's code, which takes very strange result:

```
   var offset = 0
   var a = new Buffer(0)
   var b = new Buffer('test')

   offset = a.length
   a.length += b.length
   a.copy(b, offset)
   console.log(a.toString())
   // everything works normaly
   // returns: test

   b = new Buffer('hello')
   offset = a.length
   a.length += b.length
   a.copy(b, offset)
   console.log(a.toString())
   // code the same
   // but returns: test<Buff
   // nor: testhello

   // at the third time code doesn't works and raise error: targetStart out of bounds
```

What do I do wrong?

Comment: The function ran nicely for me :/

Comment: What version of node.js is this ?

Comment: I'm not sure if it is advisable to alter the buffer length like this, I'm actually surprised that Node even allows it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

:EDIT:

Got confused by the question. I thought he is going to handle buffers of same type.

Buffers cant be resized as they are defined by a fixed size in Node.js so the best option is to use a function like this

```
   function concat(buffers) {

    if (!Array.isArray(buffers)) {
      buffers = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    }

    var buffersToConcat = [], length = 0;
    buffers.forEach(function (buffer) {
        if (!Buffer.isBuffer(buffer)) {
          buffer = new Buffer(buffer);
        }
        length += buffer.length;
        buffersToConcat.push(buffer);
    });

    var concatinatedBuffer = new Buffer(length), index = 0;
    buffersToConcat.forEach(function (buffer) {
      buffer.copy(concatinatedBuffer, index, 0, buffer.length);
      index += buffer.length;
    });

    return concatinatedBuffer;
  }
```

**What were you doing wrong?**
You were trying to manipulate the length of a fixed size allocation in memory by the 
+= method.  Hence it threw exception beacause += operator obviously didnt re-allocated memory

**What are we doing here **

Pretty simple we are just making a new buffer out of the argument buffers.

Comment: As a result variable „a“ becomes string, nor Buffer. 
That's nice when you work with strings, but wrong when you work with binary Buffers.

Comment: from your example i got confused >_>

Comment: Why the `if (buffer)` in the first `forEach`? I mean, you're in `forEach`, of course it's going to exist. Something I'm not seeing? :p